# Set column size for Tmux run-shell command

Tags: tmux

I would like set the size of the shell used in the Tmux `run-shell` command to be the same number of columns as the currently displayed window.

Using the following command

```
bind \ run-shell "tput cols"
```

I see that the column size is always set to 80. How do I change this to be the same as the current window?

I plan on using this to update my current key binding to echo the copy buffer into my system's pasteboard. (I'm on a Mac)

```
bind \ run-shell "reattach-to-user-namespace bash --noprofile -c 'tmux show-buffer -b 0 | pbcopy'"
```

This currently wraps all lines at 80 characters. Very annoying for long lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapping comes from using `show-buffer`. It is better to use `save-buffer` for this case; it does not “massage” the data in any way (`show-buffer` also does strvis(3) encoding).

The default for the buffer commands is to use the first buffer (index 0); this makes `-b 0` effectively the the default, so you can leave it off.

There is no need to use an extra shell like that. Just use the wrapper directly on *pbcopy*.

```
bind \ run-shell "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
```

---

In answer to your actual question, there is no quick and easy way to do what you ask. The environment for the process started by `run-shell` is derived from the server’s “global” environment and is not actually a part of any particular session, window, or pane. There is currently no way to absolutely know which session, window, or pane was active when a `run-shell` was executed through a binding.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Guess I'm going back to what I thought was a work around writing to a temp file and cating that to pbcopy.